# Efficient way to manipulate bits in byte array representing a bitfield

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

So, I have a byte array that represents a bitfield. A bit 1 at any index of a byte array implies that I have the corresponding piece and vice versa for a 0. Now, I need to change the bit value of 0 to 1, whenever I have the corresponding piece.

My question is, is it better if I convert the byte array to an int array and then change the corresponding value of the array index or is it simpler to do it in a byte array?

If it's the former, how can I convert the byte array to an integer array? If it's the latter, how do I change the value of the corresponding byte array?

Comment: You can use [bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). There is no need for converting to other integer.

Comment: Why aren't you using the builtin `java.util.BitSet` class?  It is intended for exactly this use case.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you! I did not know of its existence.

Comment: Also note that  BitSet uses a long[] internally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if bit n is true

```
boolean get(int n, byte[] bitField)
{
    return (bitField[n >> 3] & 1 << (n & 0x7)) != 0; //or use n / 8 and n % 8
}
```

To set bit n

```
void set(int n, byte[] bitField, boolean value)
{
    if(value)
        bitField[n >> 3] |= 1 << (n & 0x7);
    else
        bitField[n >> 3] &= ~(1 << (n & 0x7));
}
```

---

If you use a [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), it's a bit simpler

To instantiate

```
BitSet bitField = new BitSet(); //can specify size
```

To check if bit n is true

```
bitField.get(n);
```

To set bit n

```
bitField.set(n, value); //can also use set(int) and clear(int) instead
```