# BitSet only grows with true bits and not false?

Tags: java, bitmap, bitset

Currently with Java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS on a Linux host (but would expect 8+ compatibility):

in the context of computing a picture in order to send a binary bitmap to some hardware that only knows a 1-bit depth of display, I am using the `BitSet` for the first time and I get some disappointing results: while populating the `Bitset` in a loop via the `set(int bitIndex, boolean value)` method, the resulting `ByteArray` has not always the same size, which does not suit the hardware that always expect the same 1024 bytes payload.

Here is s SSCCCE that illustrates my problem, the result is when I am trying to set a bit at 0, the structure does not grow. On real data I often get arrays way below the expected 1024 (e.g. 592). What I am missing?

```
8192 iterations
pixels has size of 1024
8192 iterations
pixels has size of 0    <== WTF?!
8192 iterations
pixels has size of 0    <== WTF?!
```

```java
import java.util.BitSet;

public class TestBitset {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BitSet bs = new BitSet();
        int c = 0;
        for (int band = 0; band <= 7; band++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 127; x++) {
                for (int bit = 0; bit <= 7; bit++) {
                    boolean val = true;
                    bs.set(band * 128 * 8 + x * 8 + bit, val);
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c + " iterations");
        byte[] pixels = bs.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("pixels has size of " + pixels.length);
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        bs = new BitSet();
        c = 0;
        for (int band = 0; band <= 7; band++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 127; x++) {
                for (int bit = 0; bit <= 7; bit++) {
                    boolean val = false;
                    bs.set(band * 128 * 8 + x * 8 + bit, val);
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c + " iterations");
        pixels = bs.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("pixels has size of " + pixels.length);
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        bs = new BitSet(8192);
        c = 0;
        for (int band = 0; band <= 7; band++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 127; x++) {
                for (int bit = 0; bit <= 7; bit++) {
                    boolean val = false /*bit % 7 == 1*/;
                    bs.set(band * 128 * 8 + x * 8 + bit, val);
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c + " iterations");
        pixels = bs.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("pixels has size of " + pixels.length);
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess BitSet doesn't even track unset bits, i.e. it doesn't know how many of them are past the last one which is set. It operates in terms of ["logical" length](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#length())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the Javadoc of [Bitset#toByteArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray--) for a BitSet `s`:

> Returns a new byte array containing all the bits in this bit set. More
> precisely,
>
> if `byte[] bytes = s.toByteArray();`
>
> then `bytes.length == (s.length()+7)/8`

Note that [BitSet#length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length--) is documented as

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one. Returns **zero** if the BitSet contains **no** set bits.

Now, as *all* bits in loop 2 and 3 were initialized as `false`, `s.length() = 0` and
`bytes.length` will thus evaluate to `0+7/8` = `0` (int).

Therefore, the observed length of the `byte[]` in loop 2 and 3 is correct.

Comment: I missed that notion of logical size, but during some tests I noticed that the size was correct if I am doing a `set(8192, true)`... So I cannot use the BitSet to stuff some bits individually and translate it to a `byte[]` :(

Comment: @Seki Your conclusion is correct.

Comment: @Seki not directly, no.

Comment: @DavidConrad I have found a practical workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544940/317266) to manipulate directly the bits in a byte array, and while discussing with a colleague I figured that I could have probably use a hack by setting the bit #8193 then limiting the resulting byte array to the first 1024 bytes.